# Add a word in a specific position in a non empty text file in C

Tags: c, file

I am a beginner in C and I am trying to add the word "NIKOS" which I want to be the first word in my text file but my problem is that when I write the word in my file this word is  overwrited at the word "my"
How can avoid this mistake?

My code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("file2.txt","w");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exist");
        return 8;
    }
    
    char c;
    char *p[5]={"my","french","bulldog","barks"};
    char **p1;
    int num1=0;
    for(p1=p ; *p1 ; p1++)
    {
        fputs(*p1,fp);
        fseek(fp,1,SEEK_CUR);   //afino keno 
        } 
    
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    
    fputs("NIKOS",fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_CUR);
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inserting arbitrary lengths of text into an existing file anywhere but the end isn't generally something you can do.

Comment: If you want to replace or insert text into a text file, the best bet is to rewrite the whole file. A common technique is to copy all the contents to a new file, while doing the modifications needed, and then rename the new file as the old file.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude I thought to pass all  the words in an array and to write it in my file again but I would thought if there is an an another approach

Comment: OT: What do you expect `fseek(fp,1,SEEK_CUR)`to do?

Comment: Using an in-memory buffer instead of a new file works as well. But there's really no other way to do it. Unless you're replacing a part of the file with another part which is ***exactly*** the same length.

Comment: @4386427 It will move the "cursor of my file" one position from the current psoition

Comment: @Βill97 But you are already at the end so how will you move it?

Comment: @4386427 `fseek(fp,1,SEEK_CUR)` I did it because I wanted the words to have a space between them but when I  am out of the for loop I did `fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET)` so I  returned to the beginning of the file

Comment: When you seek beyond the end of the file you create a *hole* (on supported file-systems), not a space. When reading a file with holes they will be read as zeros.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude 
  I did not know that
 what can cause in my program a hole?
  Also I  created a for loop in which I read form the file every character but it does not print a zero in my terminal https://imgur.com/a/FfI3fFW

Comment: @Βill97 If you want a space then put a space, e.g. `fputs(" ",fp);`

Comment: Writing to files never **inserts** the new data, it **replaces** data already present.

Comment: You open the file with `"w"` so, you truncate/destroy prior contents. You want a temp file. Read input from file, change it, write to temp. rename temp back to original: `FILE *fin = fopen("file2.txt,"r"); FILE *fout = fopen("file2.txt.TMP,"w"); while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fin)) {  change_data(buf); fputs(buf,fout); } fclose(fin); fclose(fout); rename("file2.txt.TMP","file2.txt");`